# angularjs twitter bootstrap confirm dismiss modal

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-bootstrap

I am trying to have a second modal popup to confirm closing the current modal.  It works fine with a button from the modal calling $scope.closeConfirm but I am trying to override $modalInstance.dismiss to also call $scope.closeConfirm but can't seem to get this to work.  Any help is appreciated.

```
'use strict'

angular.module("app").controller "ModalCtrl", ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', '$modalInstance', '$modal', ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $modalInstance, $modal)->

    $modalInstance.dismiss = $scope.closeConfirm()

    $scope.close = ->
        $modalInstance.close(true)

    $scope.closeConfirm = (newcase) ->
        _scope = $scope
        modalInstance = $modal.open(
            animation: true
            templateUrl: '/views/confirm.html'
            controller: 'ConfirmCtrl'
            size: 'sm')

        modalInstance.result.then ((response) ->
            _scope.close()
            return
        ), ->
            return

    return
]
```

Comment: Not sure if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/uu9ko31p/) is what your are looking for or not

Comment: yeah that's what I got so far, but I want the confirm popup to also appear if the user clicks on the background to dismiss the modal window